# Why channel does not get closed?

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

For the below code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func emit(c chan string) {
    words := []string{"The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "ran", "away"}

    for _, word := range words {
        fmt.Printf("send %s\n", word)
        c <- word
    }
    fmt.Printf("Close the channel\n")
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    wordChannel := make(chan string)

    go emit(wordChannel)

    word := <-wordChannel
    fmt.Printf("receive %s \n", word)

    word = <-wordChannel
    fmt.Printf("receive %s \n", word)

    word = <-wordChannel
    fmt.Printf("receive %s \n", word)

    word, ok := <-wordChannel
    fmt.Printf("receive %s %t\n", word, ok)

    word, ok = <-wordChannel
    fmt.Printf("receive %s %t\n", word, ok)

    word, ok = <-wordChannel
    fmt.Printf("receive %s %t\n", word, ok)

}
```

---

Below is the output:

```
send The
send quick
receive The 
receive quick 
send brown
send fox
receive brown 
receive fox true
send ran
send away
receive ran true
receive away true
```

---

Why sender go-routine does not close the channel?

Comment: Because you're not waiting for it to get closed.

Comment: @JimB how to ensure channel get closed before main go routine exits?

Comment: First, the channel doesn't need to be closed in this example. The standard mechanism to wait for goroutines is `sync.WaitGroup`, but this case does not need that, just range over the channel if you want to rely on closing the channel.

Comment: Refer  https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization and https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4

Comment: @JimB just to understand from resource leak aspect... Is `c` a reference type that points to queue allocated in heap? Or does `c` use file descriptor table entry in process control block?

Comment: @overexchange: the implementation does not matter (though the source is there if you want to know). `close` is not a cleanup operation, it sends a "close" message over the channel, and prevents the sending of any more messages.

Comment: @JimB As per the output, Why the sender(`emit()`) is blocked after every send of two strings, on a channel?

Comment: @overexchange: beause the only happens before guarantee you have here is that "send X" is printed before "receive X", the next "send Y" may get interleaved. Maybe put some sleep calls in there to slow it down to help you understand the order of operations.

Comment: @JimB is it interleaving of go-routines or internal queue size of channel? Because `make(ch string, 3)` has changed the behavior

Comment: @overexchange: There is no internal queue size of the channel, because it's an unbuffered channel. If you make it buffered, of course the behavior will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `main` goroutine ends without coordinating with the emit goroutine to know that it's finished.    When the end of `main` is reached, the program - and all its goroutines - ends regardless of whether any go routines may still be processing, unless you explicitly wait for them.

Closing the channel *can* help communicate the `emit` goroutine's completion to `main`.  In this case, and using the two-value response from the channel read as in

```
word, ok = <-wordChannel
```

*does* expose the state of the channel (open or closed) to `main`, but you never use it to control the flow of main.  Further, you have an *exact* the number of reads *hard coded* into main.  So, even if you *were* controlling flow with a channel close , you would never attempt a final read to see the closed channel.

Luckily, the solution with go can be quite simple.  `range`ing over a go channel will read values until the channel is closed.  So you can simplify your code, remove the explicit number of channel receives, and use the channel close to signify `emit`'s completion, all with this more concise version:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func emit(c chan string) {
    words := []string{"The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "ran", "away"}

    for _, word := range words {
        fmt.Printf("send %s\n", word)
        c <- word
    }
    fmt.Printf("Close the channel\n")
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    wordChannel := make(chan string)
    go emit(wordChannel)
    for word := range wordChannel {
      fmt.Printf("receive %s \n", word)
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get what I perceive to be your desired output:

```
$ go run t.go
send The
send quick
receive The
receive quick
send brown
send fox
receive brown
receive fox
send ran
send away
receive ran
receive away
Close the channel
```

This "`range` over a `channel`" syntax is conceptually equivalent to something like this, just a little more elegant looking:

```
func main() {
    wordChannel := make(chan string)
    go emit(wordChannel)
    for {
      if word, ok := <-wordChannel; ok {
        fmt.Printf("receive %s \n", word)
      } else {
        break
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: @mh-cbon: this is ranging over the channel, so `main` is blocked until the channel is closed, which happens after the print statement.